# Manipulating Private variables of parent class from child class

Tags: java

I am provided with UML's for two classes, the parent class `base` which has variable `balance` listed as a private member (-), and a child class, `child`. I've created the public getters/setters for `balance`. Child class has a void function `interest` that applies the appropriate equation to calculate interest (with given interest rate) and stores the result back in `balance`.

```
public class base{
    private double balance;
    //constructors and getter/setters
}
```

When I try the following I get the error: `error: unexpected type` and I'm aware that I can't do `balance =...` since `balance` is private.

```
public class child extends base{
    private double interestRate;
    //constructors and getter/setters
    public void interest(){
        super.getbalance()*=Math.pow((1+interestRate/12), 12);
    }
}
```

The only way I've thought of doing this is through using protected instead of private for `balance`, but professor is pretty strict about sticking to the UML's.

Comment: So why not just call both the getter and setter? Something like `setbalance(getbalance() * /* math... */);` should work? Hard to tell without you showing us a full [mre] though

Comment: you can use the setter for balance, right?

Comment: Ah good catch @UnholySheep! Just getting into OOP and inheritance so I wasn't too sure about using my public methods in the child class method. I'm also pretty new to Stackoverflow, what else would I need (lets say for this case) to create a reproducible example? Would I include my getters/setters aswell?

Comment: @mr.glazes you would need a runnable main class demonstrating your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you created public getters and setters, judging from your code it seems the getter is called `getbalance`. You can use the setter, then, I'll assume it's called `setbalance`. Also, you do not need to explicitly use `super`, since public methods belonging to the parent class are automatically passed to the child class (although you can, if you prefer):

```java
    public void interest(){
        setbalance(getbalance()*Math.pow((1+interestRate/12), 12));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to say, is that `protected` was invented just for the use case you are talking about. So, apart from the reason to make your teacher happy (or being an unreasonable purist) , I don't see a reason why not to use it here. In real life cases you should use it just like that.

Now, if we are theorizing and your teacher wants it private, you stick to the getters/setters. Nothing can stop you to use them, even from the child class.

```java
public void interest(){
    setBalance(getBalance()*=Math.pow((1+interestRate/12), 12));
}
```

You don't even need to use `super`. Use it only in constructors, or when you are overriding methods and want to refer to the implementation in the parent.